# Bad subsitution when trying to do string replacement with parameter expansion

Tags: bash, sh, substitution, string-substitution, parameter-expansion

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I'm writing a very small Gedit external tool for compiling `.qrc` (Qt resource files) on a key press. This is my code:

```sh
echo $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH
pyrcc $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH -o ${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH/.qrc/.py}
```

Running the above, I get

```sh
/home/user/.local/lib/python3/qrecartivi/resources.qrc
/home/user/.config/gedit/tools/new-tool: 12: /home/user/.config/gedit/tools/new-tool: Bad substitution
```

where line 12 actually is the 2n line of my sh code (This offset is due to gedit adding some comments in).
I just cannot figure out why this substition should be wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `${name/from/to}` is a `bash` feature; you are likely not executing your script with `bash`.

Comment: @chepner i'm using dash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comment by @chepner, the syntax `${var/str1/str2}` is not supported by your shell interpreter (Dash) which is strictly POSIX-compliant.

You have two solutions:

- Use Bash which supports this kind of variable substitution
- Use a POSIX-compliant way to substitute an extension with another. Like this for example:

```
pyrcc "$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH" -o "$(basename "$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH" .qrc).py"
```